# AIR for Desktop (Windows)

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Is there a "Best" version of Windows that runs AIR the best?

The AIR application mainly plays MP4s and still images in a loop.

Also, when publishing for AIR 3.4 for Desktop what are the best settings?

What should be selected from the below?
Hardware Acceleration:

1. None
2. Level 1 - Direct
3. Level 2 - GPU

Render Mode:

1. Auto
2. Direct
3. CPU

Thanks!

Comment: If your whole application revolves around video, it's best to just use stage video (uses the native hardware instead of flash player), then it doesn't matter which setting you use.   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html

Comment: Thanks LDMS, right now it uses video (10-15 seconds long) and images and loops them.  We have also talked about playing a few swfs that pull some dynamic feeds (weather, news, etc...) as well for the community center.  I will look into stage video though for the video aspects.

Comment: GPU will be your best bet then.  Direct is for using Stage3D (things like the starling framwork etc).

Comment: Roger that.  Yeah the videos are really short basically to promote local community events.  Images only play for about 10 seconds then fade out.  So from your and esdebons suggestions choose Level2 - GPU and then within the AIR3.4 Desktop settings choose Auto (render).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The GPU is to use with graphic objects (besides that normally responds faster).
- The CPU When your code makes many calculations.

In my opinion, you should then use:

Level 2 - GPU

Render Mode: Auto

Comment: Thanks Esdebon!  There really isn't much for calculations and code per se.  It is mainly used to load in some videos for a community center and then loop them.